# How to return list of all elements on page using xpath

Tags: appium

Will this line of code

```
List<WebElement> els = user.mDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
```

populate a list with all element present on the page?

is `//*` the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples, but suggest that You refrain from this design, try using smaller scope of elemnts, instead complete page.

```
List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));

List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("*"))

List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("html"))
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Yes xpath //* will return all the elements of web page.
// means relative xpath and * says match any node
But yes as recommended above use with lower range in order to see the elements.
Try printing the size/counts of webelements returned or print text of few elements

```
 List<WebElement> els = user.mDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"))
 syso(user.mDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*")).size());
 for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
  els.get(i).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ruby, you can invoke ruby block to loop in all the elements that share similar xpath or id.

```
`$driver.find_elements(xpath: 'xpathname').each do |xpath|
   puts xpath.text
   puts xpath.id
   puts xpath.value
   puts xpath.checked?
end`
```